# What is ActivityThread?

Tags: android, android-service

In Android app, I'm analyzing an `ActivityThread` error raised (I'm using Android Studio). `ActivityThread` results to be an huge class... the problem seems to be not documented anywhere! Can you define exactly what is this?

---

Logcat:

```
2019-12-19 13:55:43.955 3547-3547/nnnne.domains.dd.android E/ActivityThread: Service nnnne.domains.dd.android.PlatformService has leaked ServiceConnection com.jj.npp.internals.ServiceClient$1@2f8eb30 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service nnnne.domains.dd.android.PlatformService has leaked ServiceConnection com.jj.npp.internals.ServiceClient$1@2f8eb30 that was originally bound here at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1532)
```

Comment: please post your stacktrace with logcat

Comment: It is difficult to see logcat and stacktrace in a comment. In the future it is better to edit your original post and put code and logs there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation added to the [*`ActivityThread`*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java) class itself. No public documentation as it is hidden (part of android framework) class.

```
/**
 * This manages the execution of the main thread in an
 * application process, scheduling and executing activities,
 * broadcasts, and other operations on it as the activity
 * manager requests.
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
public final class ActivityThread extends ClientTransactionHandler {
..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to understand how `ActivityThread` is working. That's not relevant here.

The error is clear. The component `nnnne.domains.dd.android.PlatformService` leaked a `ServiceConnection`. That `Service` didn't cleanup its `ServiceConnection` when the `Service` was destroyed.

Comment: I have to resolve some thread related issues connected to error... so I think it's relevant.

Comment: Well, I don't understand your problem then. You can, of course, read the source code for `ActivityThread` if you want to.

Comment: A documentation can be useful sometimes :)

Comment: `ActivityThread` is part of the Android framework. The source code is the documentation (pretty much). You don't ever interact with `ActivityThread` directly. This class is responsible for managing the main (UI) thread, launching other components, dispatching events, delegating work to other Android framework components, etc.